# how to load JS,CSS files dynamically to avoid performance issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Intially i was given all JS files when page loads. even page doesn't require few files at the time loading the page.
Now, Performance Issues happening. So, How to load JS,CSS files dynamically?

Comment: How many files are you loading? Surely it would take hundreds to slow the browser down. And as for loading them dynamically you will need to make script and style tags in the head of your document with JavaScript.

Comment: No, not hundreds - I usually have about 10 to 40 JS/CSS files (I have one per JS Object/Class), and that slows things down dramatically. Combining into a sinlge file gives a massive speed saving, regardless of the size of the concatenated file. It seems to be all about the number of HTTP requests...

Answer (score 2):

Not quite an answer to your question, but I notice you say "files", as in more than one. I've got dramatic performance improvements by combining and minimising JS (*and CSS*) files, as suggested by the [Yahoo! performance analysis](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html). The minimiser is [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use one of the already built JavaScript loading libraries.

One of the first I used is called [LabJs](http://labjs.com/)

Another one that I have used is [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) but that would change the way you write you JavaScript code.  It actually may force you to write more modular JS code.  One of the drawbacks of RequireJS is you may run into a problem with some JS libraries that wont load but they now have a shim that allows you to work around this.